# Custom button in firefox for specific task

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I've created a custom button in firefox by following some tutorials in developer forums. Anyway what the button currently does is that it will open a specific url which is specified in *button.js* file. The current content of that file is,

> CustomButton = {
>
> 1: function () {
>
> const url = "http://www.google.com/"
>
> document
>       .getElementById("content")
>
> .webNavigation
>
> .loadURI(url, 0, null, null, null)
>
> },
>
> }

Now, what I want to implement is that by clicking the button it should open a new tab with a modified url of current tab. For example, if my browser is in *www.abc.com* then when I click the button it should open *www.abcx.com* or *www.abc.com/x* in a new tab. How can I edit the *button.js* to achieve this?

Comment: I followed the tutorial in this link for doing this : [link](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/how-to-create-and-add-firefox-navigation-toolbar-button-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends, is your button rendered as an A tag or do you append this function to an event on an existing A tag? if the last, add target="_blank" to the A tag. If not, try to force with javascript.. I do not know if you use any frameworks for this event, because I never seen anything like this before (can't believe it's best practice as well, but that is my humble opinion), but maybe you could try to do something like document.getElementById('myButton').setAttribute("target","_blank"), where 'myButton' is the ID assigned to your button tag. that will probably fire up a new tab in all major modern browsers when clicking a link. but in html, this is fairly easy by adding the target="_blank" attribute to your a.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I'm pretty newbie to this. Thanks for the reply @Koen Houtman, but I didn't understand your reply. I just need the code which if put in to that button.js file will work according to my requirement. I don't really wanna understand the concept or anything behind this, because this is actually not the focus of my work. I hope you guys understand this.

Comment: Sure thing, but can you add more of context, like HTML, or the link where you found the tutorial? I'll probably be able to help you then :)